# How to delete image from CoreData in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, crud, binary-data

I have two Entities in my CoreData one is `Photos` and other one is `Folder`. The `Folder` has `one to many` relationship with `Photos` Because of one folder can have multiple photos. Both entities has one attribute. `Photos` have `image` as attribute whose dataType is Binary Data and `Folder` has attribute name `folderName` with DataType String.

I am saving and fetching images which is working fine but deleting images from CoreData is not working for me.

here is my DataManger Class:

```
class DataManager {
static let shared = DataManager()
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CoreDataRelationship")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()


func folder(name: String) -> Folder {
    let folder = Folder(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    folder.folder_name = name
    return folder
}


func photo(image: [UIImage], folder: Folder) -> Photos {
    let photo = Photos(context: persistentContainer.viewContext)
    
    let myImagesDataArray = convertImageToData(myImagesArray: image)
    //to store array of images using encoding
    var images: Data?
    do {
        images = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myImagesDataArray, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    } catch {
        print("error")
    }
    photo.setValue(images, forKeyPath: "image")
    folder.addToPhotos(photo)
    return photo
}


func folders() -> [Folder] {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Folder> = Folder.fetchRequest()
    var fetchedFolders: [Folder] = []
    
    do {
        fetchedFolders = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error fetching folders \(error)")
    }
    return fetchedFolders
}

func photos(folder: Folder) -> [UIImage]  {
    var imageDataArray = [Data]()
    var myImagesdataArray = [Data]()
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Photos")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "folder = %@", folder)
    do {
        let result = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for data in result {
         imageDataArray.append(data.value(forKey: "image") as! Data)
      }
    } catch let error as NSError {
      print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    //fetch image using decoding
    imageDataArray.forEach { (imageData) in
      var dataArray = [Data]()
        dataArray = unarchiveDocument(unarchivedObject: imageData)//try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: NSArray.self, from: imageData) as! [Data]
          myImagesdataArray.append(contentsOf: dataArray)
    }
    
    let imagesArray = convertDataToImages(imageDataArray: myImagesdataArray)
    return imagesArray
}

//Core Data Saving support
func save (){
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
func deletePhoto(photo: Photos) {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.delete(photo)
    save()
}

func deleteFolder(folder: Folder) {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    context.delete(folder)
    save()
}


func convertImageToData(myImagesArray: [UIImage]) -> [Data] {
    var myImagesDataArray = [Data]()
    myImagesArray.forEach({ (image) in
        myImagesDataArray.append(image.pngData()!)
    })
    return myImagesDataArray
}

func convertDataToImages(imageDataArray: [Data]) -> [UIImage] {
  var myImagesArray = [UIImage]()
  imageDataArray.forEach { (imageData) in
      myImagesArray.append(UIImage(data: imageData)!)
  }
  return myImagesArray
}

func unarchiveDocument(unarchivedObject:Data) -> [Data] {
    do {
        if let document = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(unarchivedObject) as? [Data] {
            return document
        }
    } catch {
        // do something with the error
    }
    return []
} }
```

and here is my deletion code :

```
@objc func deleteTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    var deleteNeededIndexPath: [IndexPath] = []
    for(key,value) in dictionarySelctedIndexPath {
        if value {
            deleteNeededIndexPath.append(key)
        }
    }
    
    for i in deleteNeededIndexPath {
        let photo = photos[i.item]
        photoTobeDelete.append(photo)
    }
        var deletedPhoto = DataManager.shared.photo(image: photoTobeDelete, folder: folder!)
        DataManager.shared.deletePhoto(photo: deletedPhoto)
    
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: deleteNeededIndexPath)
        dictionarySelctedIndexPath.removeAll()
}
```

this code generates no error or crash but the images is not deleting from CoreData.
Anyone please guide me where I am doing wrong.
Help will be appreciated. Thanks... :-)

Comment: Another major issue is that in `photo(image:, folder:)` you create _new_ `Photos` objects from the image array and return them and then you delete these new objects leaving the original `Photos` objects untouched. It looks more like an architectural issue where you need to rethink how to handle your Photos objects in in your app including of course what @vadian writes above.

Comment: @vadian Can you please explain I didn't get which array behaviour you are talking about?